# If col 2 has q then print the val in col 1 and if col 2 does not have q then print the same val in col 2

Tags: awk

```
A01_106367192   A01_106367192
A01_106359962   A01_106359962
A01_106106644   A01_106106656
A01_106045906   A01_106045909
A01_105865211   A01_105865216
A01_105877866   q
B01_114451441   q
A01_105801529   A01_105801532
A01_105803107   A01_105803079
A01_105803074   A01_105803079
A01_105061789   A01_105061763
A01_105408577   A01_105408577
A01_104975080   A01_104975074
A01_104994687   A01_104994690
A01_104983310   q
A01_104542183   A01_104542186
A01_104652672   q
A01_104652685   A01_104652679
A01_105006416   A01_105006421
A01_105136838   A01_105136837
A01_104359686   q
A01_104359660   A01_104359665

awk '{if ($2 == q) print $1; else print$2 }' input_file |less
```

Returns col 2 as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
awk '{if ($2 == q) print $1; else print$2 }' input_file
```

This will print `$1` if `$2` is equal to the `awk` variable `q`.  This variable is uninitialized, so the test is not likely to ever be true, unless you define `q` as *the string* `"q"` on the command line:

```
 awk -vq="q" '{if ($2 == q) print $1; else print $2 }'
```

What you probably want is to compare with `"q"` in the code itself:

```
awk '{if ($2 == "q") print $1; else print $2 }' input_file
```

Or, in a more idiomatic way of saying the same thing:

```
awk '$2 == "q" { print $1 } $2 != "q" { print $2 }'
```

or,

```
awk '$2 == "q" { print $1; next } { print $2 }'
```

or, as [RomanPerekhrest's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398982/116858) shows, using the ternary `?:` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Short **awk** approach:

```
awk '{ print ($2=="q"? $1:$2) }' file
```

- `$2=="q"? $1:$2` - ternary condition, means: if the expression `$2=="q` is evaluated as `true` - print the left operand `$1`, otherwise - print the right operand `$2`

The output:

```
A01_106367192
A01_106359962
A01_106106656
A01_106045909
A01_105865216
A01_105877866
B01_114451441
A01_105801532
A01_105803079
A01_105803079
A01_105061763
A01_105408577
A01_104975074
A01_104994690
A01_104983310
A01_104542186
A01_104652672
A01_104652679
A01_105006421
A01_105136837
A01_104359686
A01_104359665
```